# VB Access MsgBox to return SQL Query WIth Multiple Results

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to return multiple values to a message box output in MS Access using VB, I have been successful so far using the below code, I now need to extend so the message box outputs comma separated distinct month names.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Qry_MonthName")
 If Not rs.EOF Then
MsgBox "Records Loaded Are For The Month Of: " & rs.Fields(0)
End if
```

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: So you want a list of Months separated by commas instead of a new msgbox for each month?

Comment: Yes exactly, the query is returning distinct month names from the table, I need to see where there is more than one month name in the table and output via msgbox, separated by comma.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strOutput As String
Dim i As Integer

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Qry_MonthName")

With rs
    'test for empty recordset
    If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        For i = 0 To (.RecordCount - 1)
            'test for last record
            If i = (.RecordCount - 1) Then
                'last record
                strOutput = strOutput + !yourField
            Else
                'all other records
                strOutput = strOutput + !yourField + ", "
            End If

            .MoveNext
        Next
    End If
    .Close
End With
    'execute messagebox
    MsgBox strOutput
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks very much both of these answers got me the desired output thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the comma separated string in the loop and then msgbox that string with something like this:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim mthString as string
mthString=""
Set rs=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Qry_MonthName")
 If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.firstMove
      Do Until rs.EOF
      mthString = mthString & rs.Fields(0) & ", "
      rs.MoveNext ' if you forget this an infinite loop will occur
     Loop
   End if
' remove last comma
mthString=left(mthString,len(mthString)-2)
msgbox "Records loaded for the months: " & mthString
```

Comment: That `rs.firstMove` will generate an error. And you can actually remove the whole If block `If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.firstMove` with associated `End if` but you'll get an error if `mthString = ""` - should check for empty string before extracting Left value

Comment: It is `rs.MoveFirst` not `rs.firstMove`. Also as far as I know it is not safe to make the assumption that Access will open a recordset on the first record so the proper way to check for no records is `if rs.BOF=False OR rs.EOF=False' (or use NOT instead of =False, but it looks cleaner not confusing the OR and the NOTs). It is possible that your recordset will open at the end (rs.EOF=True) even if there are records which is why you have to check that the cursor is not at the beginning and at the end at the same time, which can only happen with zero records returned.